# What can I say of an $m$-dimensional submanifold $S$ of an $m$-dimensional manifold $M$?

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology

I consider a differentiable manifold $M$ of dimension $m$. Let be $S$ a submanifold of $M$ of the same dimension $m$.

What can I say about $S$?

I have tried to prove that $S$ is open but I get stuck.
My idea was to use the inverse function theorem to the inclution $i:M \rightarrow S$.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Repeat of 
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84577/open-subsets-in-a-manifold-as-submanifold-of-the-same-dimension