# Are open local embeddings equivalent to local diffeomorphisms? (Do not use immersions)

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, retraction

[Open immersions are equivalent to local diffeomorphisms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3301330/are-open-immersions-equivalent-to-local-diffeomorphisms-not-algebraic-geometry), and immersions are equivalent to local embeddings, so obviously yes. I would like to understand why open local embeddings equivalent to local diffeomorphisms **without using immersions** as equivalent to local embeddings.

1. This is how I understand local embeddings and local diffeomorphisms, and why I think open local embeddings equivalent to local diffeomorphisms. **Is this correct?**

   - Local diffeomorphism:

   > For $X$ and $Y$ smooth manifolds [with dimensions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3220878/a-manifold-with-boundary-has-dimension-at-least-1-if-it-has-a-dimension-and-if). A function $f:X\to Y$,
   >   is a **local diffeomorphism**, if for each point x in X, there exists an open set $U$ containing $x$, such that $f(U)$ is open in $Y$ and $f|_{U}:U\to f(U)$,
   >   is a diffeomorphism.

   - Local embedding:

   > For $X$ and $Y$ smooth manifolds [with dimensions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3220878/a-manifold-with-boundary-has-dimension-at-least-1-if-it-has-a-dimension-and-if). A function $f:X\to Y$,
   >   is a **local embedding**, if for each point x in X, there exists an open set $U$ containing $x$, such that $f(U)$ is a regular submanifold of $Y$ and $f|_{U}:U\to f(U)$,
   >   is a diffeomorphism.

   The only difference then is the codimension of $f(U)$ in both definitions. The codimension of (each) $f(U)$ is zero if and only if (each) $f(U)$ is open if and only if $f(X)$ is open if and only if $f$ is an open map.
2. [This definition of local diffeomorphism](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WVRu.png) *as stated* is wrong, if not some different definition, as talked about [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3269623/for-local-diffeomorphisms-is-the-fu-open-in-range-assumption-redundant) because the definition is missing any of the 4 following equivalent conditions: $\dim N = \dim M$, $F$ is an open map, $F(N)$ is an open subset of $M$, or each $F(U)$ is open (Mindlack may have an issue with the last one! Haha). Yesterday I thought it could be a different definition, but then I realized that tangent spaces aren't introduced until 2 sections later, so I think this is indeed a mistake and not a different definition. (This is not exactly a problem in the book because whenever local diffeomorphisms are involved, we usually have an assumption of $\dim N = \dim M$.)

**My question 2 initially was**: What is the definition *as stated* a definition of then?

Initially, I thought it could define local embedding (equivalent to immersion, introduced 2 sections later; embedding is introduced 5 sections later) or [local diffeomorphism onto image](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3298630/what-is-the-definition-of-local-diffeomorphism-homeomorphism-onto-image). After some thought, shown in the edits [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3298630/what-is-are-the-definitions-of-local-diffeomorphism-onto-image), I change question 2 now:

**My question 2 now is**: Is the following correct?

- 2A. The definition *as stated* does not define local embedding, local diffeomorphism onto image or local diffeomorphism.
- 2B. (2A) is because the definition *as stated* does not describe the manifold structure of each of the $F(U)$'s.
- 2C. If each of the $F(U)$'s is open, then the definition is of local diffeomorphism.
- 2D. If each of the $F(U)$'s is open in $F(N)$, then the definition is of local diffeomorphism onto image, where $F(N)$ turns out to be a submanifold of $M$ (submanifold is not defined until 3 sections later) by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3303226/are-these-definitions-of-what-might-be-local-diffeorphism-onto-image-equival), which relies on [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/568160/submanifold-given-by-an-open-immersion).
- 2E. If each of the $F(U)$'s is a submanifold of $M$ then the definition is of local embedding.

Answer (score 1):

1. Okay for $f(U)$ has codimension $0$ iff it is open, not okay for the rest (given one $U$, you can’t know all of $f(X)$ being open if you only know $f(U)$ open).

A valid argument is that if $f$ is an open local embedding, then all the $f(U_x)$ for every $x$, are open, thus fulfilling the definition of diffeomorphism.

Conversely, if $f$ is a local diffeomorphism, then $f$ is a local embedding. Furthermore, if $V \subset X$, is an open subset of $X$, then for all $x \in V$, $f(V \subset U_x)$ is an open subset of $f(U_x)$ (thus of $Y$) containing $f(x)$, thus $f(V)$ is a neighborhood of $f(x)$. So $f(V)$ is open and $f$ is open. Therefore $f$ is an open local embedding.

2. I don’t understand your point. The idea of basic manifold theory is that we have a formalism that does not depend on dimensions or coordinates. The definition you are quoting (in the second link) is entirely correct. It does require $f(U)$ being open, of course.

Comment: Thanks! 1. "given one $U$, you can’t know all of $f(X)$ being open if you only know $f(U)$ open", I meant each of the $U$'s...

Comment: 2. Is this definition, *as stated*, which indeed does NOT mention anything *explicitly* about $F(U)$ open, $F(N)$ open, $\dim N = \dim M$ or $F$ open map, equivalent or NOT equivalent to what you understand is the definition of local diffeomorphism? Thinking about the relationships between the various smooth maps in my questions of the past week, I'm more and more convinced that Tu has a different definition of local diffeomorphism instead of that Tu mistakenly forgot to put $\dim N = \dim M$. This is evidenced by...

Comment: ... his inverse function theorem (both [6.26](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WVRu.png) and [8.12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJx7Q.png)) having an additional assumption of same dimension.

Comment: I also noticed in Momentum Maps and Hamiltonian Reduction by Juan-Pablo Ortega, Tudor Ratiu (the book I referred to in [my other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3302411/dimension-of-domain-is-greater-than-less-than-equal-to-dimension-of-range-for-a) you commented on) that their definition of local diffeomorphism $F$ is that (at least how I understand it. i could be wrong) $F$ is both an immersion and submersion.

Comment: Thus, I suspect Tu's definition of "local diffeomorphism" is actually equivalent either to local embedding or to [local diffeomorphism onto image](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3298630/what-is-the-definition-of-local-diffeomorphism-homeomorphism-onto-image). I understand the chain goes $$\text{local diffeomorphism} \implies \text{local diffeomorphism onto image} \implies \text{immersion} \iff \text{local embedding}$$

Comment: For your first comment, note that “each of the open subsets has an open image” and “each of the $U_x$ has an open image” is not the same. It is the same (with a couple of lines) provided that $f: U_x \rightarrow f(U_x)$ is always a homeomorphism. For the inverse mapping theorem: the “same dimension” assumption seems to be just to be able to compute determinants. If you phrase it in terms of an invertible derivative, that necessity vanishes.

Comment: For your second comment, my apologies, I had not noticed the definition in the first link. You indeed need $F(U)$ to be open, or it does not make any sense.

Comment: Question 1: Ugh, okay, thanks. Question 2: No need for apologies. Right, I know that *as stated* the definition for *local diffeomorphism* doesn't make sense. That's what I asked about [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3269623/for-local-diffeomorphisms-is-the-fu-open-in-range-assumption-redundant). My new question is what the definition *as stated* could possibly define. I initially...

Comment: ...thought the *as stated* definition could possibly define local diffeomorphism onto image or local embedding, but now I think it doesn't define anything since we don't know in what way, if at all, $F(U)$ is a manifold. I updated the post with some thoughts. Are my thoughts correct please?